# Login Page for Multi-Page Javascript Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, authentication

I have developed a multi-page Javascript web application.  My clients have asked me to provide a login page.  They do not need anything fancy and requested a single username and password that they can share with those who need access to certain featured within the application.  They want anybody to be able to see the application, but only authenticated users can use certain tools within the application.

I currently use an ASP.net proxy page (`.ashx` file) for handling requests to and from a 3rd party server storing the data consumed in my application.

I've never created a login system and have no idea where to begin.  I don't think I need a database for login information because there will only be one username and password.

How could I go about securely storing the username and password to authenticate with the user-submitted login information and enabling parts of the application based on whether a user is authenticated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news are that you don't need to build the login system, Microsoft did it for you. This is called the [Membership System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx). All you need to do is expose this API to your end users.

And it's a bad idea to have a single credential for everybody. It is better to assign unique credentials to each user.

Comment: I have used this before and found it to be absolute overkill if all you want is a simple username and password.

Comment: As I said, it's a really bad idea to share a single credential among all your users. But if you still want it, you don't need a database, you can even save credentials in your web.config
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46280d6e-191b-4725-bb98-c662bed9cdfc/using-webconfig-credentials-instead-of-membership-for-login

Comment: Down the road we may need something like this, but for now I think it might be overkill.  I wouldn't call my application an ASP.Net application, so how could I integrate ASP.Net Membership into a Javascript application?  What would that look like?

Comment: I would use Asp.Net REST to expose methods that can be called from js:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233572/Build-truly-RESTful-API-and-website-using-same-ASP

http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api